# Failed to resolve import "./header.tsx" from "src/main.tsx". Does the file exist? even after the header.tsx file is being deleted

Tags: vite, importerror

[Error/bug found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXvcM.png)

I tried creating a react component in a different file where i named it with the same file function name but i was unable to import it in the App.tsx file. I got thesame error even after removing the component file and from the codebase

Answer (score 1):

change to this :

```
import Header from './header.tsx'
```